# Moving site to another host give error 403 - forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, routes, amazon-route53, linode

I have a site hosted at AWS, domain name is set at AWS Route 53.

I want to move to hosting to another host, linode, and keeping AWS Route 53.

I just made a clone of original site to the new host, and works fine.
As last thing, I changed settings (in AWS routing) as:

```
myexample.com 
A 
XX.XXX.XXX.XX #changed to new IP

myexample.com
NS
ns-734.awsdns-12.net. 
ns-36.awsdns-42.com. 
ns-762.awsdns-60.org. 
ns-143.awsdns-32.co.uk.

myexample.com.
SOA
ns-574.awsdns-21.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

But the new site yield error 403 (while it works from its IP).

The new host has server configured to use server_name as "myexample.com" , so it should not be a problem at server side, but at routing.

What am doing wrong?
Do I really move also the routing dns to the new host?
I would like to keep using AWS S3, and so leave SOA and NS records.

Comment: if it works from IP but domain name a) DNS is not resolving yet, check https://www.whatsmydns.net b) domain name settings in the server is somehow wrong. No, you don't have to move DNS to the same place. I have my domains at Linode but DNS at NameCheap or vice versa.

Comment: oh I see, it will just take time. Thank you.

Comment: sure. mostly only 15-20 minutes. Might be 24 hours (unlikely). And if you see it is resolving to the new IP in whatsmydns.net, it is then your computer cache. Simply check the whatsmydns.net, best solution to figure it out.

Comment: thank you @smozgur, very useful and yes, it was also the cache.

Comment: sure, it is always either dns resolving and cache OR httpd configuration (if apache) where IP connection works.